# Azure OWASP : not uploading report into Sonar Dashboard

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, owasp

**Execute OWASP Dependency Check** task got deprecated from Azure,

[image]

So, we've integrated another OWASP task which is available and updated details as shown in the below picture, builds are getting success but report is not uploading into Sonar Dashboard,

[image]

Do I missed any settings or do we need to add any other configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

I have installed OWASP Dependency Check for a test.

According to the Extension description, the formatted reports could be manually downloaded from build pipeline artifacts.
[image]

The same as my test result, reports are available for download in pipeline summary page.

[image]

[image]

You could also whether the previous "(DEPRECATED) OWASP Dependency Check (x-plat)" task has any additional configuration to integrate with Sonar Dashboard.

Seems the "(DEPRECATED) OWASP Dependency Check (x-plat)" task is not allowed to add even the extension is being installed

[image]

Comment: Thanks RoyWang for detail info, in pervious OWASP there was an option to integrate with Sonar **Enable SonarQube Integration**, expecting whether any similar option is available

Comment: @karthikN The current "(DEPRECATED) OWASP Dependency Check (x-plat)" task is now not supported to create the connection with Dashboard. Another workaround is that you can add the "Download pipeline artifact" task to download your 'Report'.
If the answer is helpful to you, you could highlight it to benefit more developers.

Comment: sure, once again thanks RogWang